# -[NSUserDefaults synchronize] performance issue on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, nsuserdefaults

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Practice for NSUserDefaults synchronize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600859/best-practice-for-nsuserdefaults-synchronize)

I call `-[NSUserDefault setIntegerValue:1 forKey:differentKeys];`
about 50 times, and each time with a different key,
then call `-[NSUserDefault synchronize];`

will this be a performance impact? how many times will it be a performance impact?

Comment: This could be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5600859/82813)

Comment: Also note that you don't have to call synchronize unless you are worried about your app crashing before the information is saved. iOS will synchronize the defaults every 15 seconds or so.

Comment: In general, it should not be an issue.  However, why not let INSTRUMENTS tell you if it is impacting the performance of your app?  It surely has a much better idea about that than a bunch of strangers who have never set eyes on your code, nor have any clue about what else is going on in your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will have a small performance impact. Maybe not something you notice.
However it would still be better just to call `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize];` just once, right at the end of all your set methods calls, as it will then save all your changes then to file, rather than after each individual change.

Answer (score 4):

Think of `synchronize` as a commit changes command, so if you don't need to call it every single time you set a value to defaults don't. If you're making a lot of changes to `NSUserDefaults` simultaneously then you'll probably only have to call `synchronize` once at the end. This is all depending on your specific needs.

Additionally, performance differences in this will differ as well depending on the amount of data being stored, frequency, and the capabilities of the device. Overall, I would recommend calling `synchronize` as little as possible.